# How to convert multi-class one-hot tensor to RGB in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I have a tensor with shape `[None, 128, 128, n_classes]`. This is a [one-hot tensor](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/), where the last index contains the categorical values for multiple classes (there are `n_classes` in total).
In practice, the last channel has binary values that indicate the class of each pixel: e.g. when a pixel has 1 in the channel C it means it belongs to the class C; this pixel will have 0 elsewhere.

Now, I wish to convert this one-hot tensor to an RGB image, that I want to plot on Tensorboard. Every class has to be associated with a different colour so that it is easier to interpret.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks, G.

---

**Edit 2:**

Solution added in the answers.

---

**Edit 1:**

My current implementation (not working):

```
def from_one_hot_to_rgb(incoming, palette=None):
    """ Assign a different color to each class in the input tensor """
    if palette is None:
        palette = {
            0: (0, 0, 0),
            1: (31, 12, 33),
            2: (13, 26, 33),
            3: (21, 76, 22),
            4: (22, 54, 66)
        }

    def _colorize(value):
        return palette[value]

    # from one-hot to grayscale:
    cmap = tf.expand_dims(tf.argmax(incoming, axis=-1), axis=-1)

    # flatten input tensor (pixels on the first axis):
    B, W, H, C = get_shape(camp)  # this returns batch_size, 128, 128, 5
    cmap_flat = tf.reshape(cmap, shape=[B * W * H, C])

    # assign a different color to each class:
    cmap = tf.map_fn(lambda pixel:
                     tf.py_func(_colorize, inp=[pixel], Tout=tf.int64),
                     cmap_flat)

    # back to original shape, but RGB output:
    cmap = tf.reshape(cmap, shape=[B, W, H, 3])

    return tf.cast(cmap, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1 (slow)

A possible solution, similar to the initial code is the following. Notice that this can be very slow because of a known [problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=tf.map_fn%20slow&oq=tf.map_fn%20slow&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.6623j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of TensorFlow `tf.map_fn`

```
def from_one_hot_to_rgb_bkup(incoming, palette=None):

    if palette is None:
        palette = {i: tf.constant(color, dtype='int64') for i, color in enumerate(
            ((0, 0, 0),
            (31, 12, 33),
            (13, 26, 33),
            (21, 76, 22),
            (22, 54, 66))
        )}

    # from one-hot to grayscale:
    B, W, H, _ = get_shape(incoming)
    gray = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(incoming, axis=-1, output_type=tf.int32), [-1, 1], name='flatten')

    # assign colors to each class
    rgb = tf.map_fn(lambda pixel:
                    tf.py_func(lambda value: palette[int(value)], inp=[pixel], Tout=tf.int32),
                    gray, name='colorize')

    # back to original shape, but RGB output:
    rgb = tf.reshape(rgb, shape=[B, W, H, 3], name='back_to_rgb')

    return tf.cast(rgb, dtype=tf.float32)
```

## Solution 2 (fast)

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903885/map-rgb-semantic-maps-to-one-hot-encodings-and-vice-versa-in-tensorflow/46903886#46903886) answer, a **much faster** solution can be using `tf.gather`:

```
def from_one_hot_to_rgb_bkup(incoming, palette=None):

    if palette is None:
        palette = {i: tf.constant(color, dtype='int64') for i, color in enumerate(
            ((0, 0, 0),
            (31, 12, 33),
            (13, 26, 33),
            (21, 76, 22),
            (22, 54, 66))
        )}

    _, W, H, _ = get_shape(incoming)
    palette = tf.constant(palette, dtype=tf.uint8)
    class_indexes = tf.argmax(incoming, axis=-1)

    class_indexes = tf.reshape(class_indexes, [-1])
    color_image = tf.gather(palette, class_indexes)
    color_image = tf.reshape(color_image, [-1, W, H, 3])

    color_image = tf.cast(color_image, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `imshow`[*](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) or `matshow`[*](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.matshow.html) from matplotlib to create the plot and then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49510378/1823497) or other answers of the same question to display it in tensor board.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(tf.argmax(imgs[0], axis=-1))
```

One of upsides of this approach is that you don't have to worry about the class to colors mapping.

---

to fix the code you already have, first you should note that the argument that is passed to colorize is a numpy array of length 1 instead of an int; which is not hashable so it can't be used for dictionary keys. You can convert it to `int` type simply like `palette[int(value)]`.

I have changed a few things in your code here and there and tested it on a random batch of size 1 and the final code looks like this:

```
def from_one_hot_to_rgb(incoming, palette=None):
    """ Assign a different color to each class in the input tensor """
    if palette is None:
        palette = {i: tf.constant(color, dtype='int64') for i, color in enumerate(
            ((0, 0, 0),
            (31, 12, 33),
            (13, 26, 33),
            (21, 76, 22),
            (22, 54, 66))
        )}

    # from one-hot to grayscale:
    B, W, H, _ = incoming.get_shape()   # this returns batch_size, 128, 128, 5
    cmap = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(incoming, axis=-1), [-1, 1])
    cmap = tf.map_fn(lambda value: palette[int(value)], cmap)

    # back to original shape, but RGB output:
    cmap = tf.reshape(cmap, shape=[B, W, H, 3])

    return tf.cast(cmap, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. However, I find the solution not very intuitive... I've been working on the code and updated the question with my current implementation (not working)

Comment: Thank you for the hints! I had to modify a bit your answer to solve a bug (you cannot just call "tf.map_fn(lambda: palette[int(value)], camp)" as is). I'm trying to make my code run so that I can test if the solution is correct. I will then update the answer :)

Comment: I added the solution to the problem in a new answer if you are interested :) I still upvoted your answer because it was useful to understand one problem in my old version of the code. Thanks a lot for the help! ;)

Comment: @gabriele I'm glad that you found the solution :) Take care, wash your hands frequently